# Send email using the GMail SMTP server from a Unix weberver website using php

Tags: php, email, unix, ssl, smtp

I am trying to send SMTP email using below php code.

```
    <?php

require_once "Mail.php";


$from = "info@XXXXX.com";
$to = "info@XXXXXX.com";
$subject = "Hi";
$body = "Hi,\n\nHow are you?\nDoing anything this Friday evening?\n";

 $host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";
 $port = "465";
$username = "xxxxx";
$password = "xxxxx";

$headers = array ('From' => $from,
      'To' => $to,
      'Subject' => $subject);

 $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
   array ('host' => $host,
     'port' => $port,
     'auth' => true,
     'username' => $username,
     'password' => $password)); 

$mail = $smtp->send( $to, $headers, $body );

if ( PEAR::isError($mail) ) {
echo( "<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>" );
} else {
echo( "<p>Message successfully sent!</p>" );
}

 ?>
```

While i am executing the code from unix webserver webpage. I am getting following error.

```
authentication failure [SMTP: Invalid response code received from server (code: 535, response: Incorrect authentication data)]
```

But the above code working fine in my localhost.

Please help me to finish the project.

Thanks.

Comment: what is inside "Mail.php", your code or from some framework?

Comment: *Incorrect authentication data* - sounds like you may have changed something from your localhost to your production environment. Check the username and password.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Send email using the GMail SMTP server from a PHP page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/712392/send-email-using-the-gmail-smtp-server-from-a-php-page)

Comment: @Peter: i downloaded code from pear.php.net. nothing changed in Mail.php

Comment: @esqew: same user name and password credential working from localhost.

Comment: @Halfwarr: yes already duplicated same code.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, you should enable SMTP in G-Suite, more details here:
https://support.google.com/a/answer/2956491?hl=en